Crowded semplot in r

Any suggestions on how to implement the indicator_spread? I'm new to semplot. Basically, the first row of variables are obviously too close together.
 p <- semPaths(model_out, whatLabels="est",
            sizeMan = 5,
            node.width = 1,
            edge.label.cex = .75,
            style = "ram", rotation =2, 
            indicator_spread = 3,
            mar = c(5, 5, 5, 5))

I tried inserting it into this code but r didn't like it. I got an error that said
In qgraph::qgraph(Edgelist, labels = nLab, bidirectional = Bidir,  :
The following arguments are not documented and likely not arguments of qgraph and 
thus ignored: indicator_spread

How can I space them out without leading to clutter? I plan to resize the nodes so I can put proper labels. Not sure if this would help or hinder.
Thanks!

Please [edit] your question to provide a minimal reproducible example of your code and data along with relevant errors so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Can you save the plot to a file and set the dimensions to have height > width?
